# Loading route into dynamically named view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build accordion style navigation for an app with Meteor and Angular JS. I have a list of articles like so:

State:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('articles', {
      url: '/articles',
      template: '<articles></articles>'
  });
```

`<articles>`:

```
  <div class="article-entry" ng-repeat="article in articles.list" slug="{{article.slug}}">
    <div class="inner">
      //...
      <div ui-view="{{article.slug}}"></div>
      <a ui-sref="article.content({slug: article.slug})">View article</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And then the article content:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('articles.content', {
      url: '/:slug',
      template: '<content></content>'
  });
```

`<content>` is just, you guessed it, the article content.

Is it possible to get `<content>` to show up in the `ui-view` associated with it when someone visits the `articles.content` state? How would I do this?